# jQuery get the last element after editing the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function that adds inputs to the DOM and gives them sequential ids based on the last one on the screen. However it only seems to count the actual last one from the pre-edited DOM... so for example if I have 5 inputs by default it will give all the news ones and id of 6 rather than 6,7,8 etc. How do I count the added ones?

```
addInput: function () {

    // Get the last input num
    $lastNum = $('.inputs input:last-child').length;

    // Num is last input plus 1
    $num = $lastNum + 1;

    // Input HTML
    $input = '<input type="text" name="iam' + $num + '" id="iam' + $num +'" />';

    // Only allow 10 inputs to be added
    if ( $('.inputs input').length > 9 ) {
        alert('You can only have a maximum of 10');
        return false;
    }

    // Append the input to the inputs list
    $('.inputs').append($input);

},
```

Answer (score 6):

`$('.inputs input:last-child').length` will always returns `1`, 'cause there is only one *last child*. Use `$('.inputs input').length` instead.

Answer (score 0):

There is basic logic for this which i used in one of my projects few years ago.

Place a hidden field with the count of the inputs available.

Hidden field = 0 at initial stage.

then if i add 3 new inputs my hidden field will have value = 3

i will save the details of three inputs in my database as per the requirement.

When i open the page again i will have to load three inputs by default. so i can pass the same value in hidden field also.

my function which adds new inputs will use hidden field value to increase the inputs...

**EDIT:**

in jQuery you must be having a Parent block which contents all the inputs into it.

So you can also find the inputs in the parent div.

```
$(".inputs input:[type=text]").length.
```

Please refer this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/URbws/13/)

Comment: While not what I'm asking it is something I will need to deal with later... Could you perhaps show an example of what you mean as I will need to build the inputs on page load for the extra info a user might add!

Comment: Wait for 2 min i m preparing a fiddle.